# How to duplicate webcam stream with FFMPEG and V4L2 - one copy, one scaled output

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam

I've a simple setup with one webcam. I need to use it in two tools simultaneously so I decided to duplicate it with gstreamer. Since it was a real mess I pretty fast switched to ffmpeg where I got better results.

I have a 1920x1080 30f Input stream and it should be converted into:

- 1920x1080 30f
- 1280x720 30f

I've loaded v4l2loopback with:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf 
options v4l2loopback devices=3 
options v4l2loopback card_label="OBS Virtual Camera,Clone,720p" 
options v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1
```

My Webcam can use serve formats:

```
$ v4l2-ctl  --list-formats -d /dev/video0
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    [1]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
    [2]: 'M420' (YUV 4:2:0 (M420))
```

But if I check with --list-formats-ext only mjpeg can do 30fps on 1080p.

My resulting command is:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -f v4l2 /dev/video4 -vcodec mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf scale=1280:720  -f v4l2 /dev/video5
```

The Copy version looks great, as it should. But the scaled version is very pixelated.
I think maybe its the doubled mjpeg codec.

[Screen Capture from Webcam playback with command above and no zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKQZg.png)

This is without any zoom, the window is in its native resolution. If I use the following command to get 720p directly from the camera you see the difference:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -f v4l2 /dev/video5
```

[Screen Capture from Webcam playback with command above and no zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypxQF.png)

Does someone has an idea how to fix it, so I get nearly the video quality from the second image while duplicating streams ?

Comment: Try adding `-q:v 2` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147805/ffmpeg-generate-higher-quality-images-for-mjpeg-encoding). You may also try different scaling parameters. Try `scale=1280:720:flags=lanczos`. In case you want better quality, replace `-input_format mjpeg` with `-input_format yuyv`, and encode the video twice.

Comment: -q:v 2 worked, tried the crf flag but as in your link descripted it did not worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Rotem](https://superuser.com/users/635712/rotem) commented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1734244/how-to-duplicate-webcam-stream-with-ffmpeg-and-v4l2-one-copy-one-scaled-outpu/1734427#comment2683985_1734244), `-q:v 2` helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers.